# Passing the Results of a Prolog Predicate

Tags: prolog

How does one evaluate the result of a prolog predicate to pass as an argument?
I am trying to write code to reverse pairs of elements in a list:

```
swap([A,B,C,D,E,F],R).
```

I want the result:

```
[B,A,D,C,F,E]
```

but I get this result:

```
append(append(append([],[B,A],[D,C],[F,E])))
```

Here is my code:

```
swap(L,R) :- swapA(L,[],R).
swapA([],A,A).
swapA([H,H2|T],A,R) :-  swapA(T, append(A,[H2,H]), R).
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just an observation, no pun intended: One more Prolog code that was written like Erlang...

Comment: @CookieMonster why like Erlang? why not like Haskell or C or Java or any functional or imperative language? I would say it's Erlang if he wrote `foo(42); foo(X).` but that's not the case...

Comment: Yes, it is not completely Erlang. But you are right, the main point is functonal use of predicates.

Comment: @Daniel Sopel: Please correct your question: You want `[B,A,D,C,F,E]` not `E,F` and you got `append(append(append([],[B,A]),[D,C]),[F,E]).`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several things:

- a variable starts with a capital letter, if you want to differenciate an atom from a variable, wrap it between `'`: `['A','B','C','D','E','F']`
- you do not need append to successfully implement this predicate. The complexity is way worse when using append.
- because you do not need append, you do not need 3 arguments either, 2 suffice

Here is a suggestion:

```
swapA([], []).
swapA([X, Y|T], [Y, X|R]) :- swapA(T, R).
```

And consider adding another base case if you want your predicate to hold when you have an odd number of elements in your list:

```
swapA([X], [X]).
```

Comment: @downvoter: care to comment about why you downvoted my answer ?

Comment: +1 for morale. But what about `swap([A],Xs)`. The OP wanted to "reverse pairs" in a list. There are no pairs. Shouldn't it succeed?

Comment: @false: I sticked to OP's semantics: fail on odd number of elements. But yup, a nice little `swapA([X], [X]).` can be added if necessary. Actually, my first version included it but I edited to stick to OP's version :p

Answer (score 3):

You can't call a Prolog predicate like a function. It doesn't return anything. When you pass `append(A,[H2,H])` to swap, it interprets it as data, not as code.

A Prolog clause creates a relation between N logic variables. That means in theory there is no concept of "input" and "output" in Prolog predicates, you can make a query with any combination of instantiated and non-instantiated variables, and the language will find the meaningful relation(s) for you:

```
1 ?- append([a],[b,c],[a,b,c]).
true.

2 ?- append([a],[b,c],Z).
Z = [a, b, c].

3 ?- append([a],Y,[a,b,c]).
Y = [b, c].

4 ?- append(X,[b,c],[a,b,c]).
X = [a] ;
false.

5 ?- append([a],Y,Z).
Z = [a|Y].

6 ?- append(X,[b,c],Z).
X = [],
Z = [b, c] ;
X = [_G383],
Z = [_G383, b, c] ;
X = [_G383, _G389],
Z = [_G383, _G389, b, c] . % etc

7 ?- append(X,Y,[a,b,c]).
X = [],
Y = [a, b, c] ;
X = [a],
Y = [b, c] ;
X = [a, b],
Y = [c] ;
X = [a, b, c],
Y = [] ;
false.

8 ?- append(X,Y,Z).
X = [],
Y = Z ;
X = [_G362],
Z = [_G362|Y] ;
X = [_G362, _G368],
Z = [_G362, _G368|Y] . % etc

9 ?-
```

In practice, not every predicate can be called with every combination, due to limitations in expressing the relation in a way that will not yield an infinite loop. Other cause may be extra-logic features, like arithmetic. When you see a predicate documented like:

```
pred(+Foo, -Bar, ?Baz)
```

That means it expects `Foo` to be instantiated (i.e. unified to another non-var), `Bar` to be a free variable and `Baz` can be anything. The same predicate can have more than one way to call it, too.

This is the reason you can't treat a Prolog relation as a function, in general. If you pass a compound as argument, the clauses will likely treat it just as a compound, unless it is **specifically** designed to handle it as code. One example is `call/1`, which executes its argument as code. `is`, `=:=`, `<` and other arithmetic operators do some interpretation too, in case you pass something like `cos(X)`.

Comment: Actually it succeeds or fails. Failing is more like throwing an exception than returning false (since it breaks the control flow, going back to the last choice point, instead of proceeding to the next instruction - like most languages do)

Comment: `'\+'(A)` is equivalent to `(A, !, fail)`, and `'->'(A,B)` to `(A, !, B)` (the cut relative to the operator call). In both cases, A failing will bring the program to the next choice point. And yes, Prolog uses functions in some cases, such as `is`, and `include/3`, `exclude/3` are considered extra-logic featuers (same as `findall/3`, `setof/3`, `bagof/3` etc). What I meant is that you can't interact directly with the return value of a predicate, in other words that it doesn't return any useful value that the programmer can reference to and act on.

Comment: well, I don't see how \+ A would be equivalent to (A, !, fail), nor how include or exclude are extra logical if their test predicate isn't extra logical. Anyway, return values of predicates do serve to structure programs, just as ifs, whiles and whatnot do in imperative languages. Their boolean values are just as used. I still don't get your point.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `(A, !, fail) ; true`. And I didn't mean to nitpick, it just feels weird to refer to anything in Prolog as a "function". Imperative and functional languages get that concept from math, but logic programming is rooted in theorem proving over first order logic. A clause is an inference rule, and a collection of clauses is a relation (which, as you know, is more general than a function). Of course, any Prolog **implementation** will use whatever the underlying platform provides - procedures, functions, state variables... But conceptually, that doesn't make a predicate a function.

Comment: well, conceptually, a predicate is just as much if not more a function that has for domain D^n and codomain B than a relation over D^n. I don't see what's troubling about it! Anyway, maybe our little dialog will have cleared things up for the OP.

Comment: @mgibsonbr: The code you propose is incorrect! It succeeds for `swap([1,2,3,4],[99,1,77,3]).`

Comment: @false thanks for pointing that out! I believe it's fixed now.

Comment: @mgibsonbr: And it does not terminate for `swap(Xs,[])`. Look at @Mog's solution.

Comment: @false You mean, on backtrack? I agree, but since I'm not here to fix OP's code, only to answer his question (which Mog an I already did), I won't bother to edit it further. The specs aren't clear anyway (is it `swap(+In,?Out)`, `swap(?Out,+In)` etc? Should it work for even length lists only or all lists?)

Comment: @mgibsonbr: also `swap([_|_],[]).` loops, it should fail. The missing specs are no excuse to suggest suboptimal and inefficient code: The overheads caused by using `append/3` as you do are quadratic. It could be linear. And better termination is obtained with *less* effort.

Comment: @false In that case, I removed **all** my code, since it's doing nobody no good. I substituted it for an explanation that addresses the OP doubt specifically, since Mog has provided a better answer anyway. I hope it helps!